# Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument, but I haven't set anything nonnull

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this simple code:

```
-(NSArray< UserObject *> *)loginUsers {
    return [self loginUsersForSite:nil];//Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
}

-(NSArray<UserObject *> *)loginUsersForSite:(UserDBO*)aa {
}
```

Why do I get the "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument" there? There is no nonnull here!!! What is going on?
I tried setting the parameter to (nullable UserDBO*) but then I get "Nullability specifier 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull'" . I don't unederstand where the nonnull existing specifier is... This class inherits from NSObject, implements no protocol. There is no "nonnull" in the .h file

Comment: Does this class have a .h file?  Does it inherit from anything?  Do these methods implement some protocol?

Comment: It has an h file (no nonnull there). inherits from nsobject. No protocol implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In the .h file the class was set to assume non null

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

This is what caused the problem